# determine which dynamically generated checkboxes are checked

Tags: php, checkbox

I'm trying to make a form with checkboxes which should subscribe a user to a forum in the database eventually.

I use this code to dynamically create a list of subscribed/unsubscribed forums for the current user:

```
//$checkboxes = array();
echo' <form  action="" method="post">';

while($unsubscrlist = mysql_fetch_assoc($sublist))
{
   //$checkboxes[] = $unsubscrlist['Name'];
    echo '<input type="checkbox" checked="checked"  name="subscrform[]" 
    value="' .$unsubscrlist['Name']. '  "/>' .$unsubscrlist['Name']. '   <br />';
}

while($subscrlist = mysql_fetch_assoc($notsublist))
{
   // $checkboxes[] = $subscrlist['Name'];
    echo '<input type="checkbox"  name"subscrform[]" 
    value="' .$subscrlist['Name']. '"/>' .$subscrlist['Name']. '<br />';
}

echo '<br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>';
```

Then, to determine which checkboxes are checked I use this code:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
  if(isset($_POST['subscrform'])) 
{
 //echo 'getshereeee';
    foreach($_POST['subscrform'] as $value)
    {
    //echo 'getshereeee';
            echo $value;

     }

}
```

Now the first checkboxes - to which the user is already subscribed -are output as value by this code, while the second list of checked checkboxes is never output as value somehow..

I thought this might had to do with using the same name twice. So I changed the first list to unsubscrform and did the check loop loop for both but still only get the first list as output values.

I feel like I'm missing something simple but can't really find out what. I would very much appreciate your help!

Comment: Have you tried to debug the `$_POST` variable at the start of your PHP, e.g. `echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST); echo '</pre>';`

Comment: Array
(
    [subscrform] => Array
        (
            [0] => Nieuwforum  
            [1] => photos  
        )

)
This is the result, (both 'nieuwforum' and 'photos' are from the first list of checkboxes) so apparently the second list is not included in the post at all..?:s

Comment: And is any of the second list of checkboxes actually 'checked'? HTML checkboxes that are not 'checked' will not send a value

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution to my problem!

by changing

```
echo' <form  action="" method="post">';
```

to

```
echo' <form name="subscrform" action="" method="post">';
```

Comment: Hm, that does not really make sense, a form does not need to have a name property, unless you're doing something with JavaScript that makes use of that.